How to configure the color of unselected items in a TabBar and make the bar always visible in SwiftUI
In my app I have a tab bar where I've configured the background color of the bar (black) and the color of the selected tab (orange).
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            TabView {
                Group {
                    FirstView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("One", systemImage: "1.circle")
                    }

                    SecondView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Two", systemImage: "2.circle")
                    }
                }
                .toolbarBackground(Color(red: 65 / 255, green: 65 / 255, blue: 65 / 255), for: .tabBar)
                .toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .tabBar)
                .tint(.blue)
            }
            .tint(.orange)
        }
    }
}

This works exactly how I want it to. The tab bar is always visible, no matter if there is content behind it or not and the selected tab is orange. However, I now also want to change the color of the tabs that are not selected. The default gray is difficult to see with my black background. The only way I could find to do this is by either adding UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.white or
let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.iconColor = .white
appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
UITabBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance

to the init() of my ContentView. Configuring the tab bar this way doesn't work with .toolbarBackground(for:), the styling in the constructor have no effect when .toolbarBackground(for:) is used. If I remove .toolbarBackground(for:) the styling in the constructor does have effect. The closest I got to what I want is configuring the tab bar completely in the constructor:
init() {
    let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()

    appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
    appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 65 / 255, green: 65 / 255, blue: 65 / 255, alpha: 1)

    appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.iconColor = .white
    appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]

    appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.iconColor = .orange
    appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor(Color.orange)]

    UITabBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
}

But now the tab bar isn't always visible. It looks it is not when there is no content behind it. How can I have the tab bar always visible with this configuration?
Edit
The most workable solution I have currently is this:
struct ContentView: View {
    init() {
        UITabBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false

        UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 65 / 255, green: 65 / 255, blue: 65 / 255, alpha: 1)
        UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 65 / 255, green: 65 / 255, blue: 65 / 255, alpha: 1)

        UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = .white
    }
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            TabView {
                Group {
                    FirstView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("One", systemImage: "1.circle")
                    }

                    SecondView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Two", systemImage: "2.circle")
                    }
                }
            }
            .tint(.orange)
        }
    }
}

To keep the styling in one place I've tried to set the color of the selected tab in the constructor like this UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = .orange, but for some reason that doesn't have any effect.
Bonus Question
Is there a way to change the color of the pil/bar used to push the app to the background or switch between apps (what is it even called)? Its standard, darker color makes it almost invisible against the custom color I'm using for the tab bar, so I'd like to make it white when displaying the tab bar. For sheets and other views that don't display the tab bar it can have its default color.

This post might help: SwiftUi Change Tint of Unselected Item in Tab Bar

What do you mean by "This way of configuring the tab bar doesn't work with the way I'm currently styling the tab bar"?

By that I mean that the styling in the constructor gets ignored when I use .toolbarBackground(for:) on the Group in the TabView.

Note, many SO posts say TabView should not be inside a NavigationStack. It should be the top most container.

It's been a while but I think I added that so I could have a toolbar at the top. If there is a better way to do that I'm all ears!

Well don't do toolbarBackground(for:) then. Set the tab bar background with the UIKit APIs also.

For the tab bar color that is fine, but without .toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .tabBar) the tab bar changes its color based on what is behind it which makes it appear to flicker when data is being loaded to display. That seems to be resolved by adding UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 65 / 255, green: 65 / 255, blue: 65 / 255, alpha: 1) in the constructor but that doesn't feel like the proper solution, so I'm wondering if there is a better way.
